# What is ?reqp=1&reqr=... at the end of my URL? Malicious?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, security

I'm not sure if this is a StackOverflow or more of a Programmers kind of question, but several others here have asked similar questions.

While scanning my Google Analytics account, I noticed a few exit links were tagged with the query string:

`?reqp=1&reqr=[....]`

There's no mention of it on StackOverflow, couldn't find anything in Google other than some sites that looked malicious, and I'm a bit worried.

Does anyone know how to find out what this could be? And if so, could you please point me to a JavaScript and/or Rails code solution (if it's actually a problem)?

Thanks!

Comment: "solution" usually implies a problem, so what are the symptoms?

Comment: I clarified that sentence. I'd like to know how to find out what this is, and then if it's a problem, how should I fix it. No need to seek a solution if it's not a problem :)

Comment: you can't control what URLs your clients will hit, only the result of hitting a given url. Extensions, userscripts, etc can all dance upon your html as they see fit.

Comment: You're right. I only asked this question because I've never seen query strings like that on any of my sites. When that kind of thing happens at work, it's usually someone trying to do something nasty.

Comment: i could be something, but unless it causes issues, i would consider it more noise than signal.

Answer (score 3):

this is dns hi-jacking at its finest. Just carefully check to see where the domain resolves and that its configured correctly. Blame your host if you are landing on one of their parking pages.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, the ending of a domain name having "?reqp=1&reqr=" usually indicates that the hosting package has not been purchased or expires. You should contact your hosting company to see what hosting packages are available for you. Hope this helps and have a great day!